# Graph API: ediscovery/cases/ endpoint is failing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, o365security-compliance

I am trying to use Graph API (Beta) to get the Legal Hold information from compliance.microsoft.com for my tenant. For this purpose I am using "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/compliance/ediscovery/cases" endpoint.

But when I try it from Graph Explorer I get "Unauthorized" error even after giving consent to "eDiscovery.ReadWrite.All" permission. (Though graph explorer->Modify permissions still says "Admin Consent Required"->"Yes". Not sure why.)

Seeing similar error from postman when I try after granting eDiscovery.ReadWrite.All permission to my Azure AD App.

Has anyone been able to query this endpoint? Let me know if I am missing any permission or config.

Answer (score 0):

These are the 2 permissions required for the accessing this API, you also need eDiscovery.Read.All permission , this work only for delegated permissions and you can also decode your token in jwt.ms and check scopes if those permissions are available.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I am seeing similar error from Graph Explorer. I think Graph Explorer works in delegate permission mode. So not sure why this error.